# django websocket cannot send data to client after receiving it

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-channels

```
class WSTestView(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept();

        self.send(json.dumps({'status': 'sent'})) # client receives this
    
    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=text_data) # receives user id
        serializer = NotificationSerializer(notifications, many=True).data

        self.send(serializer) # client does not receives this
```

**Frontend**

```
// ...
useEffect(() => {
    socket.onmessage = (e) => { console.log(e.data) }
  }, [])
// ...
```

I've just started with django-channels and am working on a consumer that sends the user's notifications when it receives the user's id but on the frontend the onmessage event does not receive anything, how can I fix this and is there a better way that I can implement this?

Comment: Is `serializer` a dictionary? Do you have to convert it to a JSON string - `self.send(json.dumps(serializer))`?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your front end and not django-channels if you're able to connect to it. The most probable reason is that your onmessage binds after, because of the componenDidMount/useEffect, the server has already sent the message.

Try just as a test, to rule that out. To put the

```js
socket.onmessage = (e) => { console.log(e.data) }
```

Right after the `new WebSocket...`. Let me know if that prints something in the console. Another way to test/isolate it is with an online WebSocket tester like this https://www.lddgo.net/en/network/websocket

Answer (score 0):

```
class WSTestView(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept();

        self.send(json.dumps({'status': 'sent'}))
    
    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=text_data) # receives user id
        serializer = NotificationSerializer(notifications, many=True).data

        self.send(json.dumps(serializer)) # <-------
```

1. Had to convert the serialized data into a JSON string.

**Frontend**

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.onmessage = (e) => { console.log(e.data) }
  }, [socket]) // <-------
```

2. Had to put the socket variable into the dependency array